# updating latop to 13.04 raring / no gui but only terminal is present

Tags: ati, laptop, samsung

Today I updated my laptop (Samsung NP-Z700 with hybrid graphics) to Ubuntu 13.04 Raring  and following the update I am not able to see any graphical interface. I tried installing ATI drivers from

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

but no results. Only the terminal is available.

Running `fglrxinfo` prints:

```
Error: unable to open display (null)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> yet, try that. It switches between terminals and GUI (sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

13.04 supports ends in 20 days, please update to 13.10.

The solution to your problem is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

The pxpress is for Hyrbid systems.

Then: sudo amdcccle and set the graphics to intel graphics :)